# How to make different product listing view only for a single category products

Tags: magento-1.9

now as a default the `product listing` page gives me a layout structure(design). And all categories products use this same layout.

Now i'm tyring to differentiate one special category products in different layout(designs).

Below are the two wirframe that illustrates what I'm looking for.

**Default**
[image: Default product listing page]

**Desired** product listing of one special category products lisiting layout
[image: new layout]

**Edited :**
My local.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<layout version="0.1.0">
<default>
    <CATEGORY_496>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
    </CATEGORY_496>

</default>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

K.c you can do this by `Layout xml changes.` and you need change it `Layout 1column.phtml`.

```
<action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
```

See at  http://www.amitbera.com/how-to-change-page-layout-in-magento/

page/1column.phtml

Example:guess that your `category  id` is `10`.If you want to assign `1column` desing then you need 
to put below code local.xml at `app/design/frontent/ your package/your template/layout/`

```
<CATEGORY_10>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
<CATEGORY_10>
```

Comment: i have updated my question with local.xml and it's not working as accordingly.

Comment: please check admin design setting